# Нужна помощь в том, чтобы передать строки (str) дальше в методы

Tags: java

Написал программу по обработке строк, которая принимает с консоли 5 строк и делает с ними операции ... по заданию нужно найти:

1. *Найти самую короткую и самую длинную строки. Вывести найденные строки и их длину.*(**сделано и работает**)
2. *Вывести на консоль те строки, длина которых больше средней, а также длину.*(сделал по аналогии с первым, **но не работает**)
3. *Найти слово, состоящее только из цифр. Если таких слов больше одного, найти второе из них.*(сделал по аналогии с первым, **но не работает**)

Я вижу проблему в том, что в два следующих метода не принимают **str**, подскажи пожалуйста как это решить? Использовать Arrays и ArrayList нельзя(((

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class StringProcessing {
    private final int n = 5;
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringProcessing run = new StringProcessing();
        run.stringMinMax();
        run.middleSize();
        run.differentSymbols();
    }

    public void stringMinMax() {
        String theLongestString = null;
        String theShortestString = null;
        Integer maxLength = null;
        Integer minLength = null;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String str = in.nextLine();
        maxLength = str.length();
        theLongestString = str;
        minLength = str.length();
        theShortestString = str;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
            str = in.nextLine();
            
            if (str.length() > maxLength) { 
                maxLength = str.length();
                theLongestString = str;
            }
            if (str.length() < minLength) {
                minLength = str.length();
                theShortestString = str;
            }
        }   

        System.out.println("The longest string is: " + theLongestString + "\nIts length is: " + theLongestString.length() + "\nThe shortest string is: " + theShortestString + "\nIts length is: " + theShortestString.length());
        in.close();
    }

    public void middleSize () {
        double average=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            average+=str[i].length();
        }
        average/=n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if(str[i].length()>average) {
                int j=i+1;
                System.out.println("String "+j+" length "+str[i].length()+": "+str[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void differentSymbols () {
        int index=-1;
        boolean a=false;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            a = str[i].matches("[1-9]*");
            if(a) {
                if(index==-1) {
                    index=i;
                    a=false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(str[i]);
                    index=-2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
            if(index>=0) {
                System.out.println(str[index]);
            }
        
    }
    
 }
```

Comment: Что такое str[i]? Настоятельно рекомендуется почитать про область видимости переменных.

Comment: Сначала нужно написать, что именно не работает. Привести примеры исправить ошибку, описать почему вы выбрали этот путь или код. Как код вам помог исправить ошибку или почему код не помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringProcessing {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String [] inputStrings = new String[5];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        int avg = 0, maxLength = 0, minLength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputStrings.length; i++) {
            inputStrings[i] = in.nextLine();
            avg+=inputStrings[i].length();
            if (inputStrings[maxLength].length()<inputStrings[i].length()) maxLength=i;
            if (inputStrings[minLength].length()>inputStrings[i].length()) minLength=i;
        }
        avg/=inputStrings.length;
        
        //строки минимальной и мксимальной длины
        System.out.println("MinLength : " + inputStrings[minLength]);
        System.out.println("MaxLength : " + inputStrings[maxLength]);
        
        //второе число
        System.out.println("Second number : " + checkNumber(inputStrings, 2));
        
        //длинна больше средней
        for (String str : inputStrings) 
            if (str.length()>avg) System.out.println(str);
        
    }
    
    private static String checkNumber (String [] inputStrings, int count) {
        int numberCount = 0;
        for (String str : inputStrings) 
            if (isNumber(str) && ++numberCount==count) return str;
        return "";
    }    
    private static boolean isNumber (String arg) {
        try {
            new java.math.BigInteger(arg);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ) Если не сложно, поясните что делает эта строчка new java.math.BigInteger(arg);

Comment: @Никита Кузьмищев ваша задача - понять, состоит ли строка только из цифр. другой вопрос, что само преобразование вам не требуется (что странно с точки зрения логики. зачем проверять, если потом все равно останется стринг, но для учебной задачи сойдет). собственно, эта строчка пытается распарсить стринг в число. в случае успеха возвращается true, а если это сделать не удалось, то выбрасывается исключение NumberFormatException , которое обрабатывается и возвращается false.